# How to write the javascript validation in Amount textbox(format 22.00) in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using asp.net4.0 in this aspx page one text box enter the rate, the user enter only numbers(22) it can display 22.00 like that suppose user enter 22.5 it display 22.50 pls help me how to write the code in client side javascript i am writing like this

```
function Rate(evt) {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

         return true;
     }
```

it taking only numbers, how to write the code in dot also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function isNumberWithDecimal(evt, source){
    evt =(evt)?evt :window.event;
    var charCode =(evt.which)?evt.which :evt.keyCode;
    var amt = source.value;
    var len = parseInt(amt.length);
    var ind = parseInt(amt.indexOf('.'));
    var cursorPosition = GetCursorLocation(source); 

    if(isNaN(amt)){
        evt.keyCode = 0;
        source.value = ".00";
    }
    if(charCode == 46){
        if(ind>-1)
                evt.keyCode = 0;
    }
    else if(charCode < 48 || charCode >57)
        evt.keyCode = 0;
    else{
        /* it will allow to enter only two digit after decimal point in numeric field      */
        if((len - ind)>2 && ind > -1 && cursorPosition > ind)
                evt.keyCode = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out   : num.toPrecision(4);

Example:

```
var num = 22.5;
var stringrep = "";

if(!isNaN(num))stringrep =num.toPrecision(4);  //Action is here


alert(stringrep);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Number.toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)